# Discovering a server in a local network without scanning the entire network

Tags: java, networking

I am writing a program in Java that involves one computer creating a server and another one that finds the server's IP and creates a connection to it.

The method i am looking for is similar to that of the SHAREit app. I tried to search through out the subnet in my network, 192.168.*.*, for a computer with a particular open port but it took a long time, so I'm looking for a better way.

Comment: You need to show the community what you have attempted so far, help the community help you. also you haven't actually asked a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to broadcast a message from the server, once the client receives it it will contact the server.

[example in java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/clientServer.html)